# OpenData AEMET datos recibidos erróneos

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer una petición al AEMET con el siguiente código `PHP`:

```
function httpRequest($url){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url."?api_key=".api_key, 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "cache-control: no-cache", "charset=ISO-8859-15")
     )); 
    $data = curl_exec($curl); 
    $err = curl_error($curl); 
    curl_close($curl); 

    if ($err) { 
        echo "cURL Error1 #:" . $err; 
    return $err;
    } 
    else {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

El problema es que los datos que recibo aunque aparentemente están en **ISO-8859-15** algunos caracteres se muestran como **"?"**.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Y si le pones utf8 mediante?: **`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "cache-control: no-cache", "charset=utf-8")`**

Comment: Ya lo he probado y la respuesta sale lo mismo :_(

Comment: Prueba usando el código [tal y como ellos lo muestran](https://opendata.aemet.es/centrodedescargas/ejemProgramas) (último ejemplo de código). Si sigue sin funcionar puede que sea debido a otras configuraciones en tu servidor o en el HTML que muestra los datos. Yo te recomendaría que tanto en el servidor como en el HTML uses `utf-8` como codificación. O sea, que tengas `utf-8` en todo, así no tendrás problemas con los caracteres.

Comment: Al principio usaba el código que daban como ejemplo exactamente y lo modifiqué un poco para ver si hacía algo. La cosa es que cuando tú les haces una petición te devuelven dos enlaces: uno de datos y otro de metadatos, el problema es que son dos enlaces al servidor de la aemet y uno se ve bien, con tildes, "eñes" y tal y el otro no

Comment: Puede que sea un problema a nivel de tu servidor o de tu HTML, no creo que una API que se antoja profesional arroje datos mal codificados.

Answer (score 0):

tras intentar de todo y muchos días de romperme la cabeza acabo de hacer una petición y ya me envía los datos bien...   No preguntéis el por qué, no sé si lo habrán leído la gente del Aemet o que pero ya recibo bien los datos.

Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas!